# Prevent hiding the bar when fullscreen mode in i3

Tags: fullscreen, i3-window-manager

I am using i3wm, and often I want to focus on a certain window, so I might put it in fullscreen and exit it when I need to see the other windows. This is fast, however it makes the bar dissapear (I'm using i3blocks). This makes me nervous since then I can't look at the time or battery while in fullscreen.

Is there a simple way to make it so fullscreen mode does not hide the bar?

Comment: You could just use the tabbed-view rather than fullscreen, and hide the window bars.

Comment: @larkey this seems promising, but I can't find how to hide the window bars in tabbed-layout. (they are already disabled for default layout)

Comment: Hm, apparently this isn't possible (and out of scope), so this solution does not completely work. A workaround would be to define a "fullscreen" workspace where only one window is open all of the time and add a keybind to a) move $window to that workspace and b) switch to that workspace. As it's the only window there, the borders would be hidden and using no borders for everything else, this'd basically achieve what you intent. Maybe it's even possible to bind the key s.t. you can restore the layout from before.

Comment: tabbed-view does not work as intended when your workspace has both vertical and holizontal splits